# checking to have the matched class names and do something

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want to check if i have elements with a matched className that is being dynamically generated and apply some code in this case :

say:

```
<div class="c red"></div>
<div class="c green"></div>
<div class="c red"></div>
<div class="c yellow"></div>
<div class="c red"></div>
```

i want to check if for those tags that has class "red" and apply something to them
but keep in mind that i cant call the $(".red") element directly because it can vary each time the page load and become diffrent color next time , so i want a generic solution to check if there is a match in class names in the document

Answer (score 2):

Using jQuery:

```
$('div.c').each(function(_, div) {
    if( $(div).hasClass( 'red' ) ) {
        // this div node has a class called 'red'
    }
});
```

You can either use `.hasClass()` or `.is()` to determine that. Be aware that when using `.is()` you need to qualify the string with a leading dot, like `'.red'`.

Using vanilla Javascript:

```
[].forEach.call( document.querySelectorAll( 'div.c' ), function( div ) {
    if( div.classList.contains( 'red' ) ) {
        // this div node has a class called 'red'
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks but i dont want to use the .red to i dentify the selector i just want to match any matched class names regardless of its name

Comment: @Bishak: I'm afraid I don't understand that. Can you elaborate on that  further ?

Comment: i mean that i want to check the document for exact class names , but i dont have these class names predefined it will be dynamically generated from the backend , so i cant call a class name directly , instead i need a generic check method , i appreciate your help

Comment: @Bishak: I guess we agree on that you require something.. that you can actually search for. It looks like you either need to use some server-side template engine and render those classNames into your files (as javascript), or you have some kind of ajax request, receiving that data on-the-fly at some point.